# Kill both processes at the same time

Tags: java, process

I have an assignment where I must create two instances of a process and the other process must terminate when one of them is terminated. I can only do this when I close the first process created, does this means that created processes have some kind of hierarchy, even though they are both children of the same process?

Thanks in advance.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process proc_1 = pb.start();
Process proc_2 = pb.start();
System.out.println("Child is running...wait for child to terminate");

int exitValue_1 = proc_1.waitFor();
System.out.println("Child_1 finished with exit value -> " + exitValue_1);
if(exitValue_1==0) proc_2.destroy();

int exitValue_2 = proc_2.waitFor();
System.out.println("Child_1 finished with exit value -> " + exitValue_2);
if(exitValue_2==0) proc_1.destroy();
```

Comment: You're going to need to use threads.  You would have a master thread that knows about the two child threads (and spawns them).  The two child threads would execute the processes.  When the first process returns, this child thread would inform the master thread, that would inform the still running thread.  The master thread would be waiting for the two child threads to complete...

Comment: That would do it, but I cannot use threads in this assignment.

Comment: You could use a loop and check each process's exit value (this throws an `IllegalThreadStateException` if the process hasn't exit), as soon as one returns a value without thrown an exception, it must have finished...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process#exitValue` will throw a `IllegalThreadStateException` if the process has not yet exited, you could exploit this.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process proc_1 = pb.start();
Process proc_2 = pb.start();

boolean running = true;
while (running) {
    try {
        int exitValue = proc_1.exitValue();
        System.out.println("Child_1 finished with exit value -> " + exitValue);
        if(exitValue==0) {
            proc_2.destroy();
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException exp) {
    }
    try {
        int exitValue = proc_2.exitValue();
        System.out.println("Child_2 finished with exit value -> " + exitValue);
        if(exitValue==0) { 
            proc_1.destroy();
            running = false; 
            break;
        }
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, was only focused on the int returned and had forgot the InterruptedException thrown by exitValue(). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> does this means that created processes have some kind of hierarchy,

No.  It's just the way you wrote your code.  You are blocking until the first process exits and unfortunately if the second process exits first your code has no way of knowing this.

Since Java is not providing you with a "waitForEitherProcess" method, I think you will need to do a polling loop checking the status of the process.  Periodically invoke exitValue on each process then sleep for a few milliseconds.  If exitValue returns an int, the process has terminated.  If it throws an exception it has not.  Use this to decide which process has exited and which needs to be killed.

Comment: In addition, there's the copy-pasta typo in the second println that will mean that it says that child_1 finishes first...